# GETting an image from google places photo api call

Tags: python, django, image, http, google-places-api

I'm trying to GET an image following the directions here:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos#photo_references

Everything goes smoothly: I receive the image (and can save the image if I wish). I should also point out that I'm working in python.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to display the received image in a webpage (I'm using the received image in a rendered html page) without going through the process of saving the image to a file then linking that file.

Hopefully that was clear. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, save the image in memory

Comment: I don't follow. I'm sending the rendered webpage, not viewing it myself

Answer (score -1):

The simplest option is to just do `<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?photo_reference=..." />` in the web page, rather than doing a GET of that URL in your server.

The downside of that is it exposes your API key to anyone viewing the web page.  There are various ways to avoid that, with different trade-offs:

1. proxy that request through your server (which can enforce that requests originate from your page, e.g. by checking the HTTP Referer header).  E.g. a URL path on your server like `/getphoto?photo_reference=...&maxwidth=...` that then triggers a GET to the Google Places API with those parameters plus your API key added, and passes the response back, or
2. use the [Places library for the Javascript Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/) (where you can use a Browser key that is safe to expose on your website), or
3. do the GET request server side, and encode the image into a `<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">` tag.  Unless you're only fetching thumbnail sized images I don't recommend this option.  It will add significant latency to your page load & render time, and significant memory overhead to your server.